# Looking for a translation of Toldos Yaakov Yosef

Tags: product-recommendation, translation, chasidut-hasidism

I’m looking for a translation of the Toldos Yaakov Yosef, does anyone know where I could buy one (preferably online)?

Comment: Sefaria has a free one, with some bits translated to English (not everything though): https://www.sefaria.org/Toldot_Yaakov_Yosef?tab=contents